# Transit Visa requirement for Rome

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, italy

I am travelling from India to London on a standard Visa for UK.
My return is from London to Rome and then from Rome to India. Do i need to have a transit Visa for my layover at Rome? I have a layover of 17 hours.
Please confirm ASAP as my flight is next week

Answer (score 0):

According to Timatic which I accessed through the [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) web site, assuming you're an Indian citizen, you won't need a visa if you're transitting through Rome (FCO) and remain in the international transit area of the airport.